# Is EJS not compatible with ES6?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, es6-modules

I cannot figure out what's breaking this code when changing to ES6. I get this error when hitting the home route (or any other that requires rendering): `Error: Failed to lookup view "index.html" in views directory "/Users/someguy/Documents/project/src/views"`.

This works fine in Common JS:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const ejs = require('ejs')

dotenv.config()
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.set('port', PORT);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))


app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.render('index.html')})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/scripts')));

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode in port ${process.env.PORT}`))
```

This is the only thing that changes in my ES6 version:

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import ejs from 'ejs'
import path from 'path'

const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I created it manually though. The error points to the right folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set view path before setting view engine

```
app.set('port', PORT);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile)
```